# Unique number of combinations after $z$ steps of merging items by specific rules

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, permutations, algorithms

I encountered an issue where I am trying to estimate the number of unique combinations:

There exists $N$ distinct molecules (or, for example, balls), where each molecule is labelled with some functional groups (or labels) from a set of functional groups $\{x\}$ (e.g. molecule 1 is labelled with $A,B$, molecule 2 is labelled with $C$, molecule 3 is labelled with $A,B,D$).

At every step, you can combine *two* molecules by a reaction (or rule) in a set of reactions $\{y\}$ - i.e. molecules that have specific pairs of functional groups (e.g. $A+B$, $A+C$, $B+C$, order does not matter) can merge to become a new molecule, in doing so their original functional groups remain except for those that were recombined (e.g. mol 1 + mol 2 -> new mol with only a label of $B$, but not $A$ or $C$). For each distinct molecule, you can have unlimited supply. The question is how can one quickly estimate the total number of possible molecules after $z$ steps?

From what I tried, I formulated it into a matrix $A$ of $N \times x$, where each cell $(i, j)$ is $0$ or $1$ and represents whether a molecule $i \in \{N\}$ has a functional group $j \in \{x\}$ . I know how to calculate the number of combinations after 1 step - $\sum_{j_1, j_2 \in \{y\}} \left( \sum_{i_1} a_{i_1 j_1} \times \sum_{i_2} a_{i_2 j_2} \right)$. But I am not so sure on how to do more than one step - *N* can be rather large, so ideally we would not make a new entry in the matrix to store the new molecules, but rather modify existing entries. Heuristic algorithms would be fine too, if they are fast and relatively accurate - $N$ will be around $10^4$, there will be ~5 elements each in $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mention that the initial molecules are all distinct. How do you count the newly generated ones? Are they distinct if and only if they have different sets of functional groups attached?

Comment: Also, I don't quite understand your nested sum: In the outer sum as well as in the inner sum you are iterating over $j_1, j_2$. You also use ${x}$ and ${y}$ differently in the last paragraph (i.e. not how you introduced it).

Comment: Sorry for my many questions. Here's is one more thing I wondered: Since you mention heuristic algorithms I assume that you are interested in something practical i.e. you really want to implement it. Is that correct? If yes, it would be crucial to mention how many molecules and rules there can be. For example, how large can $N$ be in your inputs?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! For your first question: the newly generated molecules are distinct if their starting molecules are distinct. Different molecules can share the same functional groups.

Comment: For your third question, yes, I'd like to implement such algorithms. $N$ would be roughly 50K, and there will be 5-6 functional groups ($\{x\}$), and 4-5 reactions ($\{y\}$). I've clarified it, thanks!

Comment: For your second question, my bad, I've corrected the last paragraph, thanks! In essence, the nested sum counts new molecules produced by each reaction, and sum them over all possible reactions (i.e. for every column (that represents a functional group), we take the sum of its elements, multiply it with the sum of another column that can react with it, and we sum over all such pairs of reactions) - I can try to formulate it better, sorry for the confusion.